# Inequality $a^{s}+b^{s}+c^{s} \leq \left( a+b+c \right)^{s}$

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c\ge 0$, $s\in\left(0,1\right)$ and $a^{s}+b^{s}+c^{s} \leq \left( a+b+c\right)^{s}$ then $a,b,c\in${$0,a+b+c$}.

Any hint, please

Comment: You wrote $a,b,c\in${$0,a+b+c$}. Don't you mean $a,b,c \in (0,a+b+c)$?

Comment: Not really, the problem was stated as such. i.e that a, b and c are  either 0 or the sum of all three.

Comment: If that's the case, the problem ask to prove that $a^s\leq a^s$ for $a\geq 0$, $s\in (0,1)$, which is ridiculous

Comment: @leo I don't think that's the case

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** By Jensen's inequality, if $a, b, c > 0$, then

$$ (a+b+c)^s > a^s + b^s + c^s.$$

Claim in your question follows after filling in some more details.

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem

Comment: the question is very strange, $a^x$ is convex so no matter $s$ is less or greater than 1.and $a,b,c$ can be any positive number.there is no limitation for the inequality.what the question really asked for?

Comment: @chenbai If the inequality holds then a, b and c are either $0$ or the sum of all three.

Comment: OK, I made a mistake. indeed, it should use $x^s$, when $0<s<1$, $x^s$ is concave function, so $(a+b+c)^s \le a^s + b^s + c^s$, if you want$(a+b+c)^s \ge a^s + b^s + c^s$, then only case is $(a+b+c)^s = a^s + b^s + c^s \implies a=b=c=0$

Comment: @chenbai not quite. All you need is 2 of them to be 0.

Comment: @CalvinLin you are right! thanks.